# What causes the red frame not to align with the grid correctly?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

What causes the red frame not to align with the grid correctly?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{diagram.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0bp]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{psgraph}{->}(0,0)(-1,-1)(3,2){4cm}{3cm}%
\end{psgraph}%
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\foreach \compiler/\ext in {latex/tex,dvips/dvi,{ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None}/ps}{\immediate\write18{\compiler\space diagram.\ext}}

\fboxsep=0bp\relax
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0){\color{red}\fbox{\includegraphics{diagram}}};
    \draw (-1,-1) grid (5,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know for sure. But just looking at the graphic I think: `anchor = south west` makes that the rectangle is shifted 2 times the linewidth in the opposite corner (“`north east`”). I mean, the graphic you input is not 4cm times 3cm but “4cm plus 2linewidth times 3cm plus 2linewidth”.

Comment: Hopefully it is a bug in TikZ. :-)

Comment: No, it has to do with `\fbox` since the rule width of `\fbox` *is* taken into account in `anchor = south west`. If you change `\fbox` to `\mbox` for instance, it does align correctly (altough no red box :P). Now, *how can you draw that red `\fbox` with a correct aligning*? I don't know (you could “move it” 2 times the line width, but *automatically*… I don't know).

Comment: Why don't you use TikZ facilities for drawing the frame?

Comment: @egreg: I did it with `fbox` by accident.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (-1.5\fboxrule,-1.5\fboxrule)
     {\color{red}\fbox{\includegraphics{diagram}}};
```

1 rule width and 0.5 for dimen=middle