# What causes my tangent and normal lines not to be visually perpendicular?

Tags: pstricks, pstricks-add

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\FPset\LabelBase{4}
\FPeval\DeltaX{pi/LabelBase}
\FPset\DeltaY{1}

\FPeval\Left{0 -pi/4 -DeltaX/2}
\FPeval\Right{2*pi +DeltaX/2}
\FPeval\Bottom{0 -3 -DeltaY/2}
\FPeval\Top{3 +DeltaY/2}

\newlength\Width\Width=8cm
\newlength\Height\Height=6cm
\newlength\urx\urx=15pt
\newlength\ury\ury=15pt
\newlength\llx\llx=-15pt
\newlength\lly\lly=-15pt

\psset
{
    trigLabels,
    trigLabelBase=\LabelBase,
    urx=\urx,
    ury=\ury,
    llx=\llx,
    lly=\lly,
    algebraic,
    plotpoints=1000,
    xAxisLabel=$x$,
    yAxisLabel=$y$, 
}

\def\f{sin(x)+sin(2*x)+sin(3*x)}
%\def\fp{cos(x)+2*cos(2*x)+3*cos(3*x)}

\def\fp{Derive(1,\f)}

\begin{document}
\begin{psgraph}[dx=\DeltaX,dy=\DeltaY]{->}(0,0)(\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top){\dimexpr\Width-\urx+\llx}{\dimexpr\Height-\ury+\lly}
    \psplot[linecolor=NavyBlue]{Pi -4 div}{TwoPi}{\f}
    \pstVerb{/xxx {Pi 4 div}def}
    \psCoordinates[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=gray](*xxx {\f})
    \psplotTangent[linecolor=Red,Derive={\fp}]{xxx}{1}{\f}
    \psplotTangent[linecolor=Green,Derive={-1/\fp}]{xxx}{1}{\f}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What causes my tangent and normal lines not to be perpendicular?

Comment: On your picture $\pi/4\approx1$, hence the deformation.

Comment: A different scaling of lengths in x- and y-axis?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I think scaling does not matter.

Comment: @FifaEarthCup2014 Of course it *does* matter! Scaling on one axis only is not an orthogonal transformation.

Comment: @FifaEarthCup2014: It was my first guess, as I have seen this error many times when I grade exams of pupils ;-)

Comment: Automatic scaling provided by `psgraph` is now no longer useful. A sad news for today!

Comment: [Hopefully it is a bug in pstricks. :-)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188415/what-causes-the-red-frame-not-to-align-with-the-grid-correctly#comment436671_188415)

Comment: @FifaEarthCup2014 It's useful. And that's how it works. That it results in two lines which don't *look* perpendicular is another thing.

Comment: @FifaEarthCup2014: Different scaling changes the slopes of lines and intersection angles too, so that they might look not perpendicular, whereas in fact they are orthogonal from a mathematical point of view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is abolutely correct! From the mathematical view the two lines are perpendicular:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\psset{yunit=2}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](3,3)
\psline(3,3)\psline(0,3)(3,0)
\psset{unit=1cm,linecolor=red}
\psline(3,3)\psline(0,3)(3,0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In your example you have different x and y units. If you do not want variable scaling then do not use `\psgraph`. It is designed for a *fixed* width and height of an image by variable scaling!

```
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-3.5)(7,4)
\psaxes[trigLabelBase=4,dx=0.75\pstRadUnit]{->}(0,0)(\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)[$x$,90][$y$,0]
\pstVerb{/xxx {Pi 4 div} def}%
\psplot[linecolor=NavyBlue]{xxx neg}{TwoPi}{\f}
\psCoordinates[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=gray](*xxx {\f})%
\psplotTangent[linecolor=Red,Derive={\fp}]{xxx}{1}{\f}%
\psplotTangent[linecolor=Green,Derive={-1/(\fp)}]{xxx}{1}{\f}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, `psgraph` allows proportinal scaling!

```
\begin{psgraph}[options](x,y)(x,y){Width}{!}
```

It is similiar to `\resizebox`

Comment: I use `psgraph` with the height dependent on the width. See my answer. :-)

Comment: That doesn't matter. You have different units if height and width are different. That's all.

Comment: Sorry. Could you make  `psgraph` draw the axes last (like `showgrid=top`) such that all plots below the axes? I don't want to invoke `\psaxes` before `\end{psgraph}` to get the same effect because it seems to be redundant.

Comment: Try http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pst-plot.tex, it knows `axespos=bottom|top`. b is the default

Answer (score 1):

Another solution just for fun! How it works?
I let the height is a function of width such that both horizontal and vertical use the same metric scale.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\FPset\LabelBase{4}
\FPeval\DeltaX{pi/LabelBase}
\FPset\DeltaY{1}

\FPeval\Left{0 -pi/4 -DeltaX/2}
\FPeval\Right{2*pi +DeltaX/2}
\FPeval\Bottom{0 -3 -DeltaY/2}
\FPeval\Top{3 +DeltaY/2}

\FPeval\NormedXUnit{1/(Right-Left)}
\FPeval\NormedYUnit{1/(Top-Bottom)}
\FPeval\factor{NormedXUnit/NormedYUnit}

\newlength\urx\urx=15pt
\newlength\ury\ury=15pt
\newlength\llx\llx=-15pt
\newlength\lly\lly=-15pt

\newlength\Width\Width=8cm
\newlength\Height\Height=\dimexpr\factor\dimexpr\Width-\urx+\llx\relax+\ury-\lly\relax

\psset
{
    trigLabels,
    trigLabelBase=\LabelBase,
    urx=\urx,
    ury=\ury,
    llx=\llx,
    lly=\lly,
    algebraic,
    plotpoints=1000,
    xAxisLabel=$x$,
    yAxisLabel=$y$, 
}

\def\f{sin(x)+sin(2*x)+sin(3*x)}
%\def\fp{cos(x)+2*cos(2*x)+3*cos(3*x)}

\def\fp{Derive(1,\f)}

\begin{document}
\begin{psgraph}[dx=\DeltaX,dy=\DeltaY]{->}(0,0)(\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top){\dimexpr\Width-\urx+\llx}{\dimexpr\Height-\ury+\lly}
    \psplot[linecolor=NavyBlue]{Pi -4 div}{TwoPi}{\f}
    \pstVerb{/xxx {Pi 4 div} def}
    \psCoordinates[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=gray](*xxx {\f})
    \psplotTangent[linecolor=Red,Derive={\fp}]{xxx}{1}{\f}
    \psplotTangent[linecolor=Green,Derive={-1/\fp}]{xxx}{1}{\f}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\begin{psgraph}[...]{->}(0,0)(x,y)(x,y){\dimexpr\Width-\urx+\llx}{!}` is easier